# Question about Hartshorne Theorem5.3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about the preparation of the proof of Theorem 5.3　in Hartshorne algebraic geometry.

**Theorem5.3.**

*Let Y be a variety. Then the set Sing Y of singular points of Y is a proper closed subset of Y.*

And I have a trouble in understanding the proof of Sing Y is proper (I understood why Sing Y is close ,so we can assume Sing Y is close).

This book claims

"To show that Sing Y is a proper subset of Y, we first apply (4.9/prop in this book that, *Any veriety X of dimension r is birational to a hepersurface Y in $ P^{r+1}$* ) to get  Y birational to a hypersurface in $ P^{n}$. Since birational varieties have isomorphic open subsets(from colloraly in this book),we reduce the case of a hypersurface."

Then I have 3 questions.

**First, In proof of this Theorem, we assume dim Y is r ,but why we can take birational hypersurface in $P^{n}$**

Is'nt it from $P^{r+1}$ ?

**Second,why we can reduce to the case of Y is hypersurface.**

I think this means if Y birational to hypersurface Z ,and if Sing Y $\ne$ Y then Sing Z $\ne$ Z. So we can reduce to the case of hypersurface because if Sing Y is proper then Sing Z is proper. but how we confirm this with the fact there are open subsets $U\subseteq{Y}$ and $V\subseteq{Z}$ with $U \cong V$.

**Third,I think isomorphism between U and V send singular point to singular point, is it correct?**

So my idea is, if Y = Sing Y then U consists of singular point ,then V also consists of singular point, then Z = Sing Z by using V is dense, but is this correct?

Comment: i forgot to state the question,is isomorphism between U and V sends singular point to singular point?
So, if Sing Y = Y  then every point of V is singular?

Comment: 1. If you need to make an addition to your question, please use the [edit] button. 2. For some information about how to write math here on MSE, please see the [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @KReiser I edit my questions, sorry for inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's correct. I think $n$ is supposed to denote $r + 1$ in this case.
2. Let $Y$ and $Z$ be birational (irreducible) varieties. Let $V, W$ be open subsets of $Y$ and $Z$ respectively which are isomorphic. If $Z$ has a nonempty open subset $U$ which is nonsingular, then $U \cap W \neq \emptyset$ by irreducibility, which is sent to a nonempty nonsingular open subset of $Y$ by the isomorphism $V \cong W$. (Here we use the following fact; that isomorphisms send nonsingular points to nonsingular points.)
3. If $\phi: V \to W$ is an isomorphism, with $\phi(P) = Q$, then $\phi$ induces an isomorphism of local rings $\phi^*: \mathcal{O}_{W, Q} \to \mathcal{O}_{V, P}$. Hence, one is regular if and only if the other is regular.